# :Extract first name initials and last names using REGEX

Tags: c#, regex, split

I have a huge list of names from which first name initials and last names have to be extracted.Please find below the sample names :

> T.-P. SU
>  H. SPRONG 
>  G. VAN MEER
>  C. PERRONE CAPANO
>  E.
>   C. PARKER-ATHILL
>  R. J. BALICE-GORDON 
>  D. B. VAZQUEZ
>   SANROMAN
>  B. P. C. CHEN 
>  J. P. BENNETT, Jr
>  T.-K.
>   KUKKO-LUKJANOV

Expected Output :

T-P         SU 
 H            SPRONG
 G            VAN MEER
 C          PERRONE CAPANO
 EC           PARKER-ATHILL
 RJ           BALICE-GORDON
 DB           VAZQUEZ SANROMAN
 BPC          CHEN
 JP           BENNETT JR
 T-K          KUKKO-LUKJANOV
 
I have used Split function to split them . Can we have better REGEX way to parse them correctly.Please suggest.

Thanks.

Comment: http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/

Comment: Please provide the expected output.

Comment: looking at the names it looks like its not a `regular data`..only using regex would not solve the problem..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following regex works with your example data:

```
((?:[A-Z][-. ]+)+) ([- A-Z]+(?:, \w+)?)
```

Example: http://www.rubular.com/r/cM87Prp2to

Group 1 will be the first name, group 2 will be the second name.  This results in the following groups, please edit your question with more detail if any of these are not what you expect:

```
T.-P. SU -> (T.-P.) (SU)
H. SPRONG -> (H.) (SPRONG)
G. VAN MEER -> (G.) (VAN MEER)
C. PERRONE CAPANO -> (C.) (PERRONE CAPANO)
E. C. PARKER-ATHILL -> (E. C.) (PARKER-ATHILL)
R. J. BALICE-GORDON -> (R. J.) (BALICE-GORDON)
D. B. VAZQUEZ SANROMAN -> (D. B.) (VAZQUEZ SANROMAN)
B. P. C. CHEN -> (B. P. C.) (CHEN)
J. P. BENNETT, Jr -> (J. P.) (BENNETT, Jr)
T.-K. KUKKO-LUKJANOV -> (T.-K.) (KUKKO-LUKJANOV)
```

Comment: Thanks , how can we include Jr in the last name in (J. P. BENNETT, Jr)

Comment: See my edit, the updated regex should now include Jr, as well as other  similar qualifiers.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution. My goal was not to provide the simplest solution, but one that can take a variety of (sometimes weird) name formats, and generate the best guess at a first and last name initial (or in the case of mononymous people) a single initial.

I also tried to write it in a way that is relatively international-friendly, with unicode regexes, although I don't have any experience in generating initials for many kinds of foreign names (e.g. Chinese), though it should at least generate something usable to represent the person, in under two characters. For example, feeding it a name in Korean like "행운의 복숭아" will yield 행복 as you might have expected (although perhaps that is not right way to do it in Korean culture).

```
/// <summary>
/// Given a person's first and last name, we'll make our best guess to extract up to two initials, hopefully
/// representing their first and last name, skipping any middle initials, Jr/Sr/III suffixes, etc. The letters 
/// will be returned together in ALL CAPS, e.g. "TW". 
/// 
/// The way it parses names for many common styles:
/// 
/// Mason Zhwiti                -> MZ
/// mason lowercase zhwiti      -> MZ
/// Mason G Zhwiti              -> MZ
/// Mason G. Zhwiti             -> MZ
/// John Queue Public           -> JP
/// John Q. Public, Jr.         -> JP
/// John Q Public Jr.           -> JP
/// Thurston Howell III         -> TH
/// Thurston Howell, III        -> TH
/// Malcolm X                   -> MX
/// A Ron                       -> AR
/// A A Ron                     -> AR
/// Madonna                     -> M
/// Chris O'Donnell             -> CO
/// Malcolm McDowell            -> MM
/// Robert "Rocky" Balboa, Sr.  -> RB
/// 1Bobby 2Tables              -> BT
/// Éric Ígor                   -> ÉÍ
/// 행운의 복숭아                 -> 행복
/// 
/// </summary>
/// <param name="name">The full name of a person.</param>
/// <returns>One to two uppercase initials, without punctuation.</returns>
public static string ExtractInitialsFromName(string name)
{
    // first remove all: punctuation, separator chars, control chars, and numbers (unicode style regexes)
    string initials = Regex.Replace(name, @"[\p{P}\p{S}\p{C}\p{N}]+", "");

    // Replacing all possible whitespace/separator characters (unicode style), with a single, regular ascii space.
    initials = Regex.Replace(initials, @"\p{Z}+", " ");

    // Remove all Sr, Jr, I, II, III, IV, V, VI, VII, VIII, IX at the end of names
    initials = Regex.Replace(initials.Trim(), @"\s+(?:[JS]R|I{1,3}|I[VX]|VI{0,3})$", "", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

    // Extract up to 2 initials from the remaining cleaned name.
    initials = Regex.Replace(initials, @"^(\p{L})[^\s]*(?:\s+(?:\p{L}+\s+(?=\p{L}))?(?:(\p{L})\p{L}*)?)?$", "$1$2").Trim();

    if (initials.Length > 2)
    {
        // Worst case scenario, everything failed, just grab the first two letters of what we have left.
        initials = initials.Substring(0, 2);
    }

    return initials.ToUpperInvariant();
}
```